# Existing web tools to digitize non-georeferenced map images?

Tags: leaflet, software-recommendations

Are there any open source web based solutions that allow you to upload an image, georeference it to a baselayer, then draw and export geojson feature data?

Possibly similar to http://geojson.io  .
But includes the ability to upload images and match them up to a baselayer.  And then digitize the features with a drawing tool.

Seems would be possible to create with Leaflet plugins like   [Leaflet.DistortableImage](https://github.com/publiclab/Leaflet.DistortableImage)

Wondering if someone has already created something similar?

Answer (score 2):

[MapWarper](http://mapwarper.net/) will do the first part of what you want.

> It's a free to use, open source map warper / map georectifier, and image georeferencer tool. Developed, hosted and maintained by Tim Waters. This project is supported by Topomancy LLC and the New York Public Library.

Once you have a referenced layer then adding some leaflet code to allow you to draw on it and save as GeoJSON is left as a (trivial) exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks, MapWarper looks really great and open source.   However, I'm unfortunately not well versed in Ruby/Rails in which its written, to be able to add the drawing tool onto it.  I think would be great to have just one website tool to do both parts.

Comment: I just realized that geojson.io is open source and written in JS and mapbox/leaflet.   So if can't find an existing all-in-one tool, I might play around with that to try to add the ability to upload a image layer to digitize from, using the mentioned leaflet distortableimage plugin.